# Build not showing up in App Store connect

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect

I'm trying to publish my first app at Apple Store and use flight test, so I was following [Apple Tutorial to upload an app to App Store Connect using archive](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev442d7f2ca).

Now I'm already have a build uploaded, as I can confirm by that error message I get when I try to upload it again:
[image]

But my Apple Store Connect dashboard do not show me that build uploaded, as you can see in the following image
[image]

I found similar questions in a lot of places, but just
[one](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/425917/build-not-showing-up-in-app-store-connect) was exactly my issue. Unfortunately, it still with no answers.

Comment: Check your email. You will get an email when the build has finished processing or if there are problems with your binary

Comment: Hello @Paulw11 that's exactly what happened. If u want to write an answer I give u best answer

Answer (score 0):

Increment build number and version number to 2.1 (or whatever is one less than your latest attempt) and try again. Sometimes it takes time for upload to appear. But if the upload is successful it should appear under the Test Flight tab.

Cheers!